# Delphi JCL/JVCL Error on install - Application failed to start correctly

Tags: delphi, jedi

Windows 10, Delphi Seattle.  Trying to install JCL/JVCL.  I had previously installed them, and was working fine until one day, I start getting errors on Delphi startup saying that it cannot find around 20 Jedi BPL files.  After talking to a guy at Embarcadero, was told this was a known issue...in the registry getting messed up.  I decided to uninstall and reinstall.  I followed manual uninstall process. (Removed packages, deleted path entries, deleted BPL files. Did NOT make any manual changes to registry).  Rebooted.  Delphi now starts up properly; no indication of missing files.  When trying to reinstall, I run install.bat for JCL first.  This is the version that I previously had working.  I get a cmd window saying "Launching JCL Installer, then immediately get a small window popup for JediInstaller.exe saying "The application was unable to start correctly(0xc00000c3). Click OK to close the application."  I tried isntalling latest version from Github.  Had to also download jedi.inc and kylix.inc, but after doing that, I still get same error.

Thinking this was a permission problem, I run cmd as Admin... No good.  I try to do an install from GetIt Package manager.  It downloads, extracts, launches installer, and then I immediately get the same error.

Note:  I still have all the JVCL folders in my Delphi palette, but there are no components in the folders.

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing this from inside an instance of the Delphi IDE running inside another version of the IDE?  I'm not sure , but this *may* throw some light on the cause.  Btw, I wouldn't trust the Delphi uninstaller to do a complete job of removing 100% of what was there previously.

Comment: I finally had to give up and just reinstall Windows :(

Answer (score 0):

I just finally had to give up and reinstall windows.. :(